# Cloning SD card causes "interface eth0 does not exist"

Tags: networking, sd-card, linux, boot-issues

I have cloned my raspberry pi SD card after customising the OS. However, when I try to boot it on a different pi, everything appears fine, but eth0 doesn't show up in ifconfig.
When I try 'ifup eth0', I get:

> ERROR: interface eth0 does not exist

I found this solution involving the file "70-persistent-net.rules" [here.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=19289)
So, when I do:

> rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

And, then reboot, the problem is solved.

What's causing this problem?
Is there a better way to solve this problem, one that can be automated?

Comment: Have you tried with an uncustomised OS? If that works it would rather point to an error in your customisation.

Comment: @joan I haven't modified the kernel. I have simply added a few cronjobs and scripts to a Incredible PBX image.

Comment: Trying with an uncustomised OS will confirm whether the customisation is at fault or not.

Comment: @joan You're right. I'll try a raspbian build and update. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules records the mapping of interface cards with their mac address to an interface name. Your master image will store it's mapping for eth0 to mac aa.bb:dd:cc:dd:ff in this file. If you now clone the SD card and boot it on another Raspberry which has a different mac ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa then this mac will be mapped to eth1 because eth0 was already reserved by the other mac address of the master image. Because you defined eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces in your master image Linux tries to startup eth0 - which doesn't exist on your cloned system.

That's an issue [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) and everybody else dealing with cloning of images  has to deal with (See [this link](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_openstack_images.html) and search for udev. It describes how to setup a base image for OpenStack and how to fix this issue).

That's what you have to do: Customize your image and as a final step just delete /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules from your master image which you now should use as a template for all cloned Raspberries. All Raspberries using this template  will not find a mac address registered for eth0 and will use their mac address for eth0 now.

Comment: Does this apply to USB too? I've having trouble with a cloned SD card on a different Raspberry, and the USB port is not working. I'm not sure about Ethernet, since the Raspberry is not within reach of a network.

Comment: I don't think so. What's the issue you get?